# Getting key value in nested Hash by key array values

Tags: ruby

Sample hash:

```
  {
    "audio" =>  {
      "audio/aac" => ["aac"],
      "audio/mpeg" => ["mp3", "mp2"],
      "audio/mp4" => ["m4a", "m4b", "m4r", "3gp"],
      "audio/ogg" => ["ogg", "oga"],
      "audio/flac" => ["flac"],
      "audio/speex" => ["spx"],
      "audio/x-ms-wma" => ["wma"],
      "audio/x-pn-realaudio" => ["rm", "ram"],
      "audio/vnd.wave" => ["wav"],
      "audio/x-musepack" => ["mpc", "mp+", "mpp"],
      "audio/x-aiff" => ["aiff", "aif", "aifc"],
      "audio/x-tta" => ["tta"]
    },
    "video" =>  {
      "video/mp4" => ["mp4"],
      "video/mpeg" => ["mpg", "mpeg"],
      "video/x-m4v" => ["m4v"],
      "video/quicktime" => ["mov"],
      "video/x-msvideo" => ["avi"],
      "video/x-flv" => ["flv"],
      "video/webm" => ["webm"]
    }
  }
```

What's the best way given a file extension to get the associated content type (first match is okay)?

Searching for "flac" should return "audio/flac".

Currently I'm using this:

```
hsh.each_key do |group|
  hsh[group].each do |k,v|
    return k if v.include?(extension)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unraveling that sort of structure is best done when it's created. But, you can loop through the various levels and get something useful from it. If I assign your initial hash to `mime_hash` I can unravel it using:

```
Hash[*mime_hash.map{ |av, types| types.map{ |mime_type, extensions| extensions.product([mime_type]) } }.flatten]
```

or more verbosely:

```
Hash[
  *mime_hash.map{ |av, types| 
    types.map{ |mime_type, extensions| 
      extensions.product([mime_type]) 
    } 
  }.flatten
]
```

Which will return:

```
{
     "aac" => "audio/aac",
     "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
     "mp2" => "audio/mpeg",
     "m4a" => "audio/mp4",
     "m4b" => "audio/mp4",
     "m4r" => "audio/mp4",
     "3gp" => "audio/mp4",
     "ogg" => "audio/ogg",
     "oga" => "audio/ogg",
    "flac" => "audio/flac",
     "spx" => "audio/speex",
     "wma" => "audio/x-ms-wma",
      "rm" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
     "ram" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
     "wav" => "audio/vnd.wave",
     "mpc" => "audio/x-musepack",
     "mp+" => "audio/x-musepack",
     "mpp" => "audio/x-musepack",
    "aiff" => "audio/x-aiff",
     "aif" => "audio/x-aiff",
    "aifc" => "audio/x-aiff",
     "tta" => "audio/x-tta",
     "mp4" => "video/mp4",
     "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
    "mpeg" => "video/mpeg",
     "m4v" => "video/x-m4v",
     "mov" => "video/quicktime",
     "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
     "flv" => "video/x-flv",
    "webm" => "video/webm"
}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `Array#product`.

Comment: map + flatten(1) = flat_map. Hash[...] takes pairs, no need to do a total flatten.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already realized the data structure you have is horrible to search in the fashion you want. Assuming you're going to be searching the same data over and over what you should do is create an index for it.

There are many ways of doing this but the simplest is probably just to flatten the hash and invert it so that your keys become values and vice-versa. That way you can simply search it by calling `content_types['flac']`

A section of the example hash might end up like this:

```
{
  "aac" => "audio/aac",
  "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
  "mp2" => "audio/mpeg",
  "m4a" => "audio/mp4",
  "m4b" => "audio/mp4",
  "m4r" => "audio/mp4",
  "3gp" => "audio/mp4",
  "flac" => "audio/flac"
}
```

Comment: Yes, the structure is not ideal, but it serves mainly for other purposes (hence the audio/video groups) in the app, and was not meant to be asked for mime type resolution by ext.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [rassoc()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-rassoc)

Definition:

Searches through the hash comparing obj with the value using ==. Returns the first key-value pair (two-element array) that matches. See also Array#rassoc.

```
a = {1=> "one", 2 => "two", 3 => "three", "ii" => "two"}
a.rassoc("two")    #=> [2, "two"]
a.rassoc("four")   #=> nil
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't quite work as expected on this kind of hash. If the keys are an array it becomes a problem since `hash["audio"].rassoc(["m4b"])` won't return anything. Do you have an example?